# Redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS for WordPress on IIS

Tags: wordpress, ssl, iis

I have a WordPress website on IIS. I have a SSL Certificate setup for the site and that is working fine when I navigate to the site via `https`.

The problem is, I can still navigate to the site via regular `http` and of course I don't get the security of the SSL certificate.

How can I divert all traffic to the site that comes through `http` to the `https`?

Is this done via the `web.config`? I've tried all sorts, but nothing worked for me.